# Is there a way to get text formatting from a csv?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, csv

I automatically get a csv of our inventory everyday at 5:19am. For one of the values of the csv, there is a large description of the product in question; the product is a vehicle from our dealership. Prior to being entered in the csv, the description is written with returns, spaces, special characters, etc. to be formatted a certain way.

I could try to set it up so when my php file updates my sql DB, it adds html tags to the description text. But I'd rather not have to do it that way.

Is there a way to get those 'text-based' formatting choices from the csv?

Here is an example of one product from our inventory:

> "1HDIPLF115Y950778","U","10861","Harley-Davidson","SCREAMIN EAGLE FAT BOY","2005","SCREAMIN EAGLE","Motorcycles & Scooters","9198","","Unspecified","Gasoline","Manual 5-Speed","14700","Blue","","","It's called a Fat Boy but you certainly don't have to be to own one. It's also a Hog. Why all the obese names for this bike? It's stripped down and ready to barrel down the highway.   We have an incredibly striking 2005 Harley Davidson Screamin' Eagle Fat Boy. It features a 1690cc pushrod V-twin 4 stroke (upgraded from the standard 88B engine on the regular Fat Boy), electronic ignition with key fob, electric starting system, 5 speed transmission, belt drive, 5.0 gallon tank, front and rear disc brakes. The Screamin' Eagle package includes a lowered rear suspension, flying teardrop shaped air cleaner cover, slash down pipes, chin spoiler pan-style seat with a decorative chrome pillion. The tank and fenders are accented by metal grind streaks of exposed steel. A Stage 1 air cleaner kit is paired with the fuel injectors with a heavy duty starter and hydraulically controlled clutch have been added as well.  This Fat Boy is a One Owner and was over 28 grand when it was purchased brand new! For half the price, you get a practically new Harley.  This one is ready to ride since you live to ride. So c'mon, put down the barbecued pork and hop on this hog. We promise it has a better bite!      Arizona Specialty Motors  1625 E Weber Drive Tempe 85281  480-454-3844        arizonaspecialtymotors.com  Our mission is simple, we want to make this your best car buying experience ever. Taking care of customers is our business. We are a small family owned business that relies on repeat and referral business. Each deal is as important as the preceding and or following deal. We make sure every customer is totally satisfied start to finish.        WE ACCEPT TRADES PAID OR NOT.  WE HAVE AGGRESSIVE FINANCING LENDERS FOR MOST SITUATIONS ZERO DOWN LOANS STARTING APR RATE 2.5% WITH UP TO 75 MONTH FINANCING ON MOST VEHICLES.  WARRANTIES AVAILABLE (CAN BE FINANCED WITH PURCHASED VEHICLE).  GAP INSURANCE AVAILABLE (CAN BE FINANCED WITH PURCHASED VEHICLE).","https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228614.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228615.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228616.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228617.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228618.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228619.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228620.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228621.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228622.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228623.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228624.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228625.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228626.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228628.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228629.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228630.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228631.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228632.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228633.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228634.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228635.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228636.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228637.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228638.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228640.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228641.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228643.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228645.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228646.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228648.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228652.jpg?dt=021920180554,https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/17238468/1009228656.jpg?dt=021920180554"

Comment: if it truly is a csv, those formatting choices either no longer exist, or are done via  html tags or entities, or characters. If the former is true, you're out of luck, if the latter, you've already got formatted text or html. At most you might need to replace returns with break tags, or vice versa, pending on your expected output.

Comment: Do you have escaped characters in your csv?  For example" \n or \r or \t ?

Comment: Bummer. It is definitely a csv. I'm just not sure how to format a huge block of text, which is how the csv gives me the description.

Comment: Try pasting the huge block of text into a code editor. Does it have returns and/or tabs? if so, you're in luck. Otherwise... all that information has been lost in translation.

Comment: Assuming that the thing that is generating the CSV file is properly escaping and encapsulating the strings there's no reason that those wouldn't survive. You should post some example CSV and the code that you're currently using to read it. That said, if you're just dumping strings with important whitespace into HTML you should be aware that HTML doesn't care about those things for display purposes. You'll want to conider using a `<pre>` tag or [CSS `white-space`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Comment: From the looks of it, you're out of luck unless you can get the csv output modified to include the information you need.

Comment: I added an example of the csv content. The description is the huge chunk of text in the middle of the example.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to upload the csv into a Microsoft Access database and choose the delimiter. It is pretty good at sorting out the info